# How to automatically publish custom image to facebook user stream

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello I am new to facebook app development and working over my first app.
My app is basically supposed to post a new photo over the users publish stream and for that purpose the first thing I’ve is image creation process which is in this way:

```
<?php
        //Image Processing:

        $brandName = "nweing";
        $imageUrl = "newimage.jpg";
        $imageId = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageUrl);

        $xCord = 5;
        $yCord = 10;
        $fontUrl = "GOTHIC.TTF";

        $imageText = "Image Text";
        echo $imageUrl . $imageId;
        $imageColor = imagecolorallocate($imageId, 255, 255, 255);
        $imageFont = 1;
        $fontSize = 16;

        //imagestring($imageUrl, $imageFont, $xCord, $yCord, $imageText, $imageColor);
        imagefttext($imageId, $fontSize, 0, $xCord, $yCord, $imageColor, $fontUrl, $imageText);

        header("Content-type: image/png");
        imagepng($imageId);
        imagedestroy($imageId);
        ?>
```

Then I’ve configured the code as directed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/) to post photos with respective app values:

```
<?php

   $app_id = "366325366724856";
   $app_secret = "b14ac6d2b7345db259599b06983e881";
   $post_login_url = "YOUR_POST-LOGIN_URL";
   $album_name = 'My Album';
   $album_description = 'My Album Description';

   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission 
   if(empty($code))
     {
       $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id 
       . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($post_login_url)
       . "&scope=publish_stream";
       echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . 
       "'</script>");
   } 
   else {
     $token_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/"
     . "access_token?"
     . "client_id=" .  $app_id 
     . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
     . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
     . "&code=" . $code;
     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);
     $access_token = $params['access_token'];

     // Create a new album
     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?"
     . "access_token=". $access_token;

     $postdata = http_build_query(
     array(
      'name' => $album_name,
      'message' => $album_description
        )
      );
     $opts = array('http' =>
     array(
      'method'=> 'POST',
      'header'=>
        'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'content' => $postdata
      )
     );
     $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
     $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url, false, 
       $context));

     // Get the new album ID
     $album_id = $result->id;

     //Show photo upload form and post to the Graph URL
     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/". $album_id
       . "/photos?access_token=" . $access_token;
     echo '<html><body>';
     echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'
     .$graph_url. ' "method="POST">';
     echo 'Adding photo to album: ' . $album_name .'<br/><br/>';
     echo 'Please choose a photo: ';
     echo '<input name="source" type="file"><br/><br/>';
     echo 'Say something about this photo: ';
     echo '<input name="message" type="text"
        value=""><br/><br/>';
     echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload" /><br/>';
     echo '</form>';
     echo '</body></html>';
  } ?>
```

But his code is about asking user to upload an image to through html form but I want the image that I made in the earlier code to get published.
So my question how I can pass that image to Graph API endpoint to be published in user stream.

Thank-you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the image to a temporary file and then use the photo upload code from [this answer](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2718610/upload-photo-to-album-with-facebooks-graph-api)

```
    $app_id = "366325366724856";
    $app_secret = "b14ac6d2b7345db259599b06983e881";
    $post_login_url = "http://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $album_name = 'My Album';
    $album_description = 'My Album Description';

    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

    //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission 
    if(empty($code)) {
        $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($post_login_url) . "&scope=publish_stream";
        echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
        exit;
    }

    // Make sure you have read & write access to this folder
    $tmpfile = "/tmp/" . md5(rand()) . ".png";

    $brandName = "nweing";
    $imageUrl = "newimage.jpg";
    $imageId = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageUrl);

    $xCord = 5;
    $yCord = 10;
    $fontUrl = "GOTHIC.TTF";

    $imageText = "Image Text";
    $imageColor = imagecolorallocate($imageId, 255, 255, 255);
    $imageFont = 1;
    $fontSize = 16;

    imagefttext($imageId, $fontSize, 0, $xCord, $yCord, $imageColor, $fontUrl, $imageText);

    imagepng($imageId,$tmpfile);
    imagedestroy($imageId);

    $token_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" .  $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($post_login_url) . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;
    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    $access_token = $params['access_token'];

    // Create a new album
    $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=". $access_token;

    $postdata = http_build_query(array('name'=>$album_name,'message'=>$album_description));
    $opts = array('http'=>array('method'=>'POST','header'=>'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','content' => $postdata));
    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url, false, $context));

    // Get the new album ID
    $album_id = $result->id;

    //upload photo
    $args = array('message'=>'Photo caption',);
    $args[basename($tmpfile)] = '@' . realpath($tmpfile);

    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' . $album_id . '/photos?access_token=' . $access_token;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    unlink($tmpfile);

    //returns the photo id
    print_r(json_decode($data,true));
?>
```